# Change the backslashes in a URI to forward-slashes with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, escaping

I'm writing an app that will let the user import pictures.  I'm running windows, so the file path that is returned when the user selects a picture has backslashes, which is what I believe to be causing javascript to fail when I pass the path to my import method.
I get the file path with a simple html file input and use a submit button with an onclick call to my javascript:

```
 <input type="file" id="photo-to-import" />
 <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="console.log($('#photo-to-import').val().replace('/\\/g','/'))"/>
```

console.log is normally where the function call would go, I've changed it for debugging.  If I hard code in a file path to a picture and go through and manually change the slashes, it imports the picture, for example, I'll copy/paste a path:

```
C:\Users\Name\Desktop\desktop app\images\imageName.png
```

into the function and change the slashes I end up with:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="onPhotoURISuccess('C:/Users/Name/Desktop/desktop app/images/imageName.png')"/>
```

and this works great.  I have tried

```
.replace('\\\\', '/')
.replace('\\', '/')
...
```

and always get the exact same output, the string is unchanged every time.

Comment: `.replace(/\\/g, '/')` you should probably make that replace global.

Comment: Are you assigning the return result?  someStr = someStr.replace('\\', '/');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `replace('/\\/g','/')` to `replace(/\\/g,'/')`, with the quotes you will be attempting to replace literal matches of the string `'/\\/g'` instead of using a regular expression literal.

For example, `'foo /\\/g bar'.replace('/\\/g','/')` will give you `'foo / bar'`, and `'C:\\Users\\Name\\Desktop\\desktop app\\images\\imageName.png'.replace(/\\/g,'/')` will give you `'C:\Users\Name\Desktop\desktop app\images\imageName.png'`.

Comment: Works! Had a feeling it was something silly I was doing, thanks very much!